# How to toggle the display property of two sibling elements on hover of one?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to toggle the display of two sibling elements when I hover on the first sibling. I want to change the display of the hovered first sibling element from block to none while its immediate or next sibling element's style changes to block from none. I was able to write a css code for that but on hover, the elements constantly flicker and alternate in a never ending loop. Below is my html and css code:

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 20px 40px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box-one {
  background: green;
}

.box-two {
  background: whitesmoke;
  display: none;
}

.box-one:hover {
  display: none;
}

.box-one:hover+.box-two {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box box-one"></div>
<div class="box box-two"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the two boxes with another `div` (`.container`) and toggle them when hovering the container:

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 20px 40px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box-one {
  background: green;
}

.box-two {
  background: whitesmoke;
}

.container {
  width: fit-content;
}

.container:hover>.box-one {
  display: none;
}

.container:not(:hover)>.box-two {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box-one"></div>
  <div class="box box-two"></div>
</div>
```

Using JS `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events, you can add the event listener with the `once: true` option only to the current item. As soon as the mouse enter, you show the new item, and only when the user leaves the current item, you add the new `mouseenter` event listener to the current item, and so on...

```js
const showNext = evt => {
  const current = evt.target
  const next = current.nextElementSibling

  if(!next || !next.classList.contains('box')) return
  
  current.classList.remove('show')

  next.classList.add('show')
  
  next.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    next.addEventListener('mouseenter', showNext, { once: true })
  }, { once: true })
}

document.querySelector('.box')
  .addEventListener('mouseenter', showNext, { once: true })
```

```css
.box {
  display: none;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 20px 40px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.show {
  display: inline-block;
}

.box-one {
  background: green;
}

.box-two {
  background: whitesmoke;
}

.box-three {
  background: red;
}

.box-four {
  background: blue;
}

.container {
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="box box-one show"></div>
<div class="box box-two"></div>
<div class="box box-three"></div>
<div class="box box-four"></div>
```

Comment: Oh yes. I tried this method but the problem I encountered with it is that it changes the background color of all boxes in the container once the cursor is in the container without it being directly on the individual element boxes. This is even more problematic when the element boxes are more than two. I plan to use it more dynamically created element boxes.

Comment: You'll have to create a single container for each pair. BTW - are you changing just the color?

Comment: No I am not changing the color alone. This is just a mockup. I am actually swapping them out with another box with more contents.

Comment: Are you going to have more than a pair of items you replace for each content, or do you have 3 cards or more that replace each other?

Comment: I am going to have more than a pair. For example: the user can decide to create 10 boxes or any amount he likes. That means that 10 additional boxes will be automatically created as a sibling for each of the boxes the user created in the DOM. On hover of any of the boxes, the dynamically created sibling box element should be displayed.

Comment: But after hovering one, it disappears, which removes the hover, and so on. That's what causing the flicker. In addition, you'll have a problem with the rate of change.

Comment: I think you'll require some JS and use mouseenter events, and not css hover.

Comment: Javascript mouseover, mouseenter and mouseleave gave the same flicker effect. Could you please help with a function.

Comment: I've added an answer using JS.